# SQLite calculation on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am currently working on an Android application that can track income/outcome of a budget. One of my database tables is named **Transaction**, and consists of:

- Amount
- Type (income/outcome)
- Date

Since this is my first application I'm not really confident with my code, especially in the database. And now I'm making a trigger that can calculate percentage of outcome in a month. Can you check it, if my code is right or not, or not efficient. Here is tiny part of my Trigger code.

In my code I want to calculate percentage of total outcome from the first of a month until the current date.

```
"CREATE TRIGGER Calc"+
"AFTER INSERT"+
"ON" +transaction+
"FOR EACH ROW" +
"WHEN (SELET * FROM amount.transaction 
WHERE (strftime ('%d','now') - strftime('%d','start of month')) 
HAVING SUM(amount.transaction WHERE type.transaction IS "outcome") /SUM(amount.transaction WHERE type.transaction IS "income") * 0.01 )"
```

Is `select * from amount.transaction` needed? Can the code be much simpler?

0.01 there is 100%

Sorry it's so messed up since I'm just starting in making Android applications and I'm not really well versed with database. If you have any suggestions, please tell me.
Thanks before

Comment: Only add triggers if you really need it. Otherwise calculate the data on-the-fly in your selects,

Comment: One big issue: `"CREATE TRIGGER Calc"+"AFTER INSERT"` is the same as `"CREATE TRIGGER CalcAFTER INSERT"`. Same for all other strings.

Comment: You need **spaces**.

Comment: @juergend aw i'm sorry, currently learning on how to use trigger on android application

Comment: @tynn thanks for information, it'll help alot

Comment: @BobMalooga can u explain more? sorry still cant grasp it well

Comment: Each of the lines above needs a space to connect the strings. Else, your syntax will be wrong.

Comment: @BobMalooga ahhh okay thanks bob

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with commentors, I don't think you need to use triggers ahead of on-the-fly `SELECT` statements.

You do need to know that quotations `"` are literal and when concatenating strings, you need to manually add spaces.

Comment: could u give me more advice how to fix it? 
my coding skill is so poor and i'm learning it manually by myself